# How to access to the Search functionality to get the map annotations similary to Maps IPhone application?

Tags: iphone, annotations, search-engine, mkmapview

I need to use in my application the search functionality used in the Maps IPhone application.
The application user should be able to search locations by a commercial name and then to select one of the annotations (pins) proposed on the map.

Is this function available to use easily?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available in MKMapView
But i will give you a suggestion

Keep a TextField and accept the user search name from that. Then by using google API get the details about the searched location

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=yourSearchName&output=xml
```

This will return all location information with latitude longitude, Parse those details.
I think Parsing will not be much complicated.

Use Annotations to pinpoint in the map with the latitude and longitude values you got from parsing.